# Можете обьяснить эту строку кода

Tags: парсер

```
convert = soup.find('li', {'data-market': 'btcuah'}).find("ul", {"class": "last price"}).text
```

Comment: советую наоборот - вы пишете, как её понимаете, или что мешает понимаю, а вас поправляют или поясняют конкретный момент. Только сами сначала в интернете поищите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В переменную convert помещается текст тегов (если они есть)  'li' с атрибутом 'data-market' равным 'btcuah', а также тег "ul" с атрибутом "class" равным "last price".